# Criar arquivo word em PHP

Tags: php, biblioteca

Tenho um arquivo docx, modelo de um contrato. Nele, os dados do comprador e outros dados são variáveis. O sistema em PHP precisa obter informações do banco de dados e substituir no arquivo docx modelo. Ou seja, manter a estrutura principal e substituir somente algumas palavras. Após, salvar o word e disponibilizar para download.

Já vi algumas bibliotecas que fazem isso, onde pode-se definir variáveis e fazer essas substituições. Porém, não lembro o nome e nem como fazer.

Alguém que poderia me ajudar? Com recursos que posso utilizar e/ou pequenos exemplos?

Exemplo: 
O documento tem um parágrafo fixo. Nesse parágrafo, uma palavra será variável definida no momento de gerar o arquivo e após personalizar o modelo, o mesmo deverá ser salvo em docx.

Comment: Não li a fundo, mas veja se isso te ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891712/opentbs-mail-merging-docx-using-php

Comment: Era exatamente isso! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o [**`PHPOffice/PHPWord`**](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord), é necessário usar `composer`, leia sobre isto:

- Então na pasta do projeto execute:

  composer require phpoffice/phpword

Depois no seu arquivo que vai executar:

```
<?php

require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

// Adiciona sessão com texto
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText('Foo bar baz, etc etc etc 1');

$section->addText('Foo bar baz, etc etc etc 2', array(
    'name' => 'Tahoma',
    'size' => 10
));

// Adiciona texto com fonte customizada
$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
    $fontStyleName,
    array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
);

$section->addText('Teste test', $fontStyleName);

// Texto com fonte diferente
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText('Foo Bar Baz');
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');

//Local para salvar o documento
$objWriter->save('exemplo.docx');
```